# media query device-width and "regular" width not working

Tags: css, iphone, ipad, media-queries, device

In the code example below there are two cubes with styles for desktop and mobile.
on the iphone for example the cube should be green whereas on desktop it should be (and is) red.
On my iPhone in portrait view I get nothing, on landscape, it is red instead of green.
Same on the iPad.
On Google Chrome Developer Tools, when I choose Apple iPhone 5 Portrait, it doesn't show the media query in the Styles, as if it weren't recognising it or something.
What am I doing wrong?

```css
/* for desktop */
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 767px) {
 #block2 {width:100px;height:100px;background:red;} 
}
/* for iPhone */
@media only screen and (min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width: 767) {
 #block2 {width:100px;height:100px;background:green;} 
}
/* for desktop */
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
 #block {width:100px;height:100px;background:red;} 
}
/* for iPad */
@media only screen and (min-device-width:768px) and (max-device-width: 1024) {
 #block {width:100px;height:100px;background:green;} 
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
<div id="block2"></div>
```

Comment: You didn't specify the `px` `max-device-width: 767` and here `max-device-width: 1024`.

Comment: thanks, i feel a bit stupid now, but thanks!

Comment: No problem, did that solve your issue?

Comment: it did actually, thx! :-)

Comment: Okay @Ollie I added that as the answer if you would like to mark correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error:

```
(max-device-width: 767)
(max-device-width: 1024)
```

to

```
(max-device-width: 767px)
(max-device-width: 1024px)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
/* ----------- iPhone 5 and 5S ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen and
(min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) and
 (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
 and (min-device-width: 320px) 
 and (max-device-width: 568px)
 and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
 and (orientation: portrait) {
}

 /* Landscape */
 @media only screen 
 and (min-device-width: 320px) 
 and (max-device-width: 568px)
 and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
 and (orientation: landscape) {

 }
```

For more details - [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: thanks, it was a little syntax error. one question though:
if i have query one:
[at]media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 1024px)
and query two:
[at]media only screen and (min-device-width: 321px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)
so basically exactly the same but once for desktop and once for tablet, do they never interfere with each other? or in other words: are these 100% reliable to target desktop and tablet respectively?